# Recursive function to sum the elements in the list

Tags: python-3.x

Even though it looks not difficult, it makes me crazy.
I couldn't even get close to an answer.
Can you guys give me any help?

*Write a recursive function `sums_to(nums, k)` that takes a list of integers and returns `True` if the
sum of all the elements in the list is equal to `k` and returns `False`otherwise.
Example:*

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3]
>>> sums_to(nums, 6)
True
>>> sums_to(nums, 5)
False
>>> sums_to([], 1)
False
```

**Note: You are *not* allowed to use any python sum function in any form, nor sum the list and then at
the end check whether it equals k. In addition, you must write sums_to as a single recursive function:
That is, you may not use a main function and a recursive helper function.**

```
# my pool code
def sums_to(nums, k):
    if nums == []:
        return False

    if nums[0] + sums_to(nums[1:], k) == k:
        return True
```

This is what I tried so far.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and ask a more specific question about what you're having difficulty with.

Comment: You forget to add the code you tried so far, if you add it, is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I could not think of a hint to give. The whole problem is about that return statement:

```
def sums_to(nums, k):
    if not nums:
        return k == 0
    return sums_to(nums[:-1], k - nums[-1])

print(sums_to([1, 2, 3], 6))
print(sums_to([1, 2, 3], 5))
print(sums_to([], 1))
```

Comment: Oh my god... I should get used to boolean things.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using recursion, you have two case, if the list is empty, or not:

```
def sums_to(nums , n):
  if len(nums) == 0:
    return n == 0
  else:
    m = nums[0]
    nums.pop(0)
    return sums_to(nums, (n-m))

print(sums_to([2,3], 5))
```